# Select fields not displaying proper values in Bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap v5.x modal dialog to handle a mailing address update form.

When the page loads, the `value=` arguments for the `<input>` fields in my modal dialog are assigned using PHP. There are 2 `<select>` fields, one for the state, the other for the country. These both have their `<option>` lists provided by PHP as well. So all this information is pre-loaded into the modal's fields before the modal is ever shown.

The `<input>` fields display properly. However, the `<select>` fields do not display the `<option>` value having the `selected` argument set. When examining the HTML, the `selected` argument is indeed set on the correct value for each field, but BS appears to somehow override these being displayed when the modal is shown. It's as if the `selected` argument was not set at all.

So is this a bug with BS5? Or is it something I'm missing? Is there a workaround JS command I need to run after the modal is shown to refresh the `<select>` fields so they will display the `selected` values?

[image]

Comment: Please include your code so we can have a better idea of what's going on...

Comment: I don't know how this will help.
`<select name="country" id="country" class="form-select" required>
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="USA" selected">USA</option>
<option value="Afghanistan" ">Afghanistan</option>
...
</select>`
The modal appears, but USA doesn't show as the selected value

Comment: Where's your code that displays the modal? It helps because it gives a full picture of what's going on. You need to include a minimal reproducible example in your original post.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. It would really help if you showed the rendered HTML.

Comment: Updated original question with a screenshot of what I'm seeing

Comment: @unpocoloco the HTML you provided is not valid. You have extra quotes when closing your `option` tags. You should adjust the way you fill the select in your PHP code.

Comment: `$( '#ADDRESS' ).modal( 'show' );`